# Em termos de performance, "character varying" ou "text" no PostgreSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, desempenho, text, varchar

Antes de postar essa pergunta eu vasculhei na internet pra saber as diferenças e desempenho de cada tipo e cheguei a conclusão que deveria discutir um pouco mais sobre esse assunto aqui com os especialistas, rs, já sei as diferenças entre `CHAR`, `CHARACTER VARYING (Varchar)` e `TEXT (Blob)`, mas o que está pegando é a performance, segundo os comentários `Varchar` e `Text` tiveram a mesma média em milissegundos, mas não é o que estou passando na real, tenho um sistema de medicina e segurança do trabalho, onde guarda-se muitos textos então tenho optado pelo tipo `TEXT`, mas isso está me saindo caro, as telas que precisam abrir esses campos tem demorado muito, quando oculto (retiro) a tela abre imediato.

A pergunta é:

Posso usar `CHARACTER VARYING` sem limitar caracteres como se fosse `TEXT` ou posso ter problemas no futuro?

A pergunta é porque pelo que tenho lido com relação a `TEXT` ou `BLOB` alguns bancos guardam esse campo separadamente da tabela e por isso devem ser usados com cuidado, explico, muita gente sai criando uma tabela assim:

```
Nome: Text
Endereco: Text
Bairro: Text
```

O velho costume do Access e isso não deve ser feito em bancos relacionais.
Qual a experiência dos amigos nesse respeito e o que vocês recomendariam?

Eu tenho tomado todas as precauções com relação a índices, tipos de dados e `selects` para melhorar a performance, quando haviam poucos dados estava tudo bem, agora a base com tabelas de 6 milhões de registros o sistema começa a demorar mais do que o esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentação do postgresql sobre char types (char, varchar e text):](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-character.html)

> There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from
>   increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few
>   extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a
>   length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance
>   advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage
>   in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the
>   three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text
>   or character varying should be used instead.

Tradução resumida: não tem nenhuma diferença significativa de performance entre os tipos, algumas outras databases tem, mas essa não, então na dúvida use text.

Agora falando de experiência pessoal no postgresql, nunca lidei com uma quantidade significativa de dados em postgresql em uma aplicação "real" (apenas outras dbs), mas já fiz alguns protótipos em cima dela com alguns bons milhões de registros e com mais de 1 coluna de texto e não tive problema de performance.

O que posso te dizer também é que é 6 milhões de registros não é nenhuma quantidade absurda para uma database madura como postgresql, se você está tendo problemas de performance eu sugiro fazer o que é sempre recomendado nesses casos: medir tudo e ver exatamente onde é o gargalo antes de sair mudando tipagem de colunas. Especular sobre o que causa problema de performance não costuma dar certo, especialmente se é algo que foge da sua especialidade.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta BrunoBR, na verdade são tabelas com media de 6 milhões e minha base tem 260 tabelas, se colocarmos que 10 tabelas tem essa quantidade, seriam 60 milhões, o que numa consulta envolvendo pelo menos 3 a 4 tabelas seria um belo trabalho a ser feito pelo processador, por isso a sutil diferença de performance entre os tipos podem fazer diferença lá no final. Estou fazendo testes e mais testes desde reestruturação de SELECTs e visualizações de dados e cheguei num momento que achei interessante saber o que os colegas dizem com respeito aos tipos de dados e suas experiências.

Comment: @Marcelo Saquei. Mas ainda assim tem tantas outras coisas mais prováveis de serem a causa da sua lentidão que o tipo, seria a últimas possibilidade que eu iria considerar. Contudo se você fez profile e esgotou todas as opção, quem sabe. 
Quando resolver o problema seria bacana dar um update no post falando se era ou não o datatype, ia ajudar outros e fiquei curioso ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Segundo a documentação não há diferença de performance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html). É neste lugar que deve vasculhar, pode evitar outros lugares.

A implementação é única, só muda o nome.

Se o problema é a tela então veja o que tem de errado na tela e não no banco de dados. Se está lento com muitos dados tem outros problemas.

Se está testando coisas iguais é para dar o mesmo resultado, se está testando coisas diferentes então o problema é a diferença do que está fazendo. Se testar errado obterá resultado errado.]

No PostgreSQL o costume é usar `TEXT` sempre que não houver motivo para usar outra coisa, e quase sempre não tem, e se tiver é nos raros casos que um `CHAR` é mais adequado (que também tem mesma performance).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Maniero, confesso que fiquei com o pé atras da  "Gorjeta" que o help do postgres dá, na programação ou há diferença ou não, trecho: "na verdade geralmente é o mais lento dos três", então é mais lento, 100 milissegundos em um registro é insignificante, mas em 6 milhões a coisa muda de figura, se estamos falando de performance então todos os requisitos devem ser olhados com cautela, usar um campo TEXT para um NOME por exemplo, não me parece uma boa prática, então como o final recomenda deve-se usar CHAR ou CHARACTER VARYING, por isso resolvi colocar esse tópico para ver a experiencia do pessoal.

Comment: Ali está falando do `char` e não do `varchar`, e mesmo que fosse, você está dizendo que o `text` é lento, o que ele diz claramente que não é. 100 milissegundos? De onde tirou isso? Mesmo o `char` só é mais lento em circunstâncias específicas onde ele foi usado onde não deveria e a diferença é absurdamente menor que esta, a não ser que esteja usando um computador da década de 80 e tenha feito um `char` enorme que só use alguns caracteres. De fato precisa de cautela, comece ter, principalmente para interpretar textos.Ele diz o oposto do que você está dizendo.Documentação é o único guia confiável

Comment: Calma ae Maniero, a discussão aqui é justamente para eliminar dúvidas quanto ao tipo de campo e não discutir sobre a confiabilidade do manual do postgres, realmente não compreendi o manual por isso estou perguntando sobre os tipos, como eu disse sou Programador e não DBA por isso minhas dúvidas, o fato de eu ter postado esse tópico é justamente por ter cautela e não sair usando qualquer tipo em qualquer lugar, estou me certificando com pessoas como você que tem conhecimento de causa, só isso. Quando ele diz "character(n)character(n)textcharacter varying" achei que estava de fora o tipo TEXT.

Comment: 100 milisegundos poderia ser 1 ou 10 ou 1000 é hipotético... me desculpe a discrepancia